# Visual Basic DownloadFile won't overwrite

Tags: vb.net, download

I'm attempting to download a file from a website using visual basic using the following code, but I keep getting the accept overwrite dialog box. Is there a way to keep Windows from presenting the overwrite file dialog? I'm not sure why this is happening because I changed the default overwrite to true.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
            "http://example.com",
            "C:\download_location",
            userName:=String.Empty,
            password:=String.Empty,
            showUI:=False,
            connectionTimeout:=100000,
            overwrite:=True)
```

Comment: How about deleting the file before download.

Comment: Good idea, thanks Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx) says:

> *showUI*
>       **Boolean.** Specifies whether to display the progress of the operation. Default is False.

This one (and any other descriptions found there) set ***no expectations about suppressing dialog box*** for overwriting the file.

So as [Vinay Pandey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669614/visual-basic-downloadfile-wont-overwrite#comment53185190_32669614), to disable the dialog box with question, delete the file beforehand by yourself. This brings also one significant advantage: if existing file has any problems (insufficient permissions, pending file locks) if forces ***you*** (as programmer) to deal with them before download is started. I mean, it is always better to handle these things by yourself than to rely on some black-box action.

```vb
If IO.File.Exists(exampleName) Then IO.File.Delete(exampleName) ' plus error handling
```

...and also mind the case if there already is a **directory** with that file name (e.g. directory called `file.txt`).